# Fee calculating

Tags: calculus, multivariable-calculus

I have a customer that would like to pay with CoD.
CoD service with my courier is 1.8% (excl VAT) of the invoice total, and invoice is €561.20 VAT included.

Now there is a courier fixed fare of €6 excl VAT.

Total excluding VAT of the courier's shipping cost is €6+1,8% = €16.23 and VAT is 22%

What is the formula to calculate how much I should insert in the CoD field in order to let the customer pay the entire CoD fee and getting exactly €561.20 in return from my courier?

Any help is appreciated, thanks!

---

Update, after doing some tests, i'm getting closer but still not the exact amount.
So far, this is the formula that get nearer to the right result, assuming that invoice total is €500:

```
((((500/0,982)+6)-500)*1,22)+500
```

where 0,982 is the constant (1-0,018) and 1,22 is the 22% VAT - result is 518.50 which, if proposed to my courier's CoD option, it returns 18.70, so a -0.20 margin of error.
Still can't figure out how to do this :(